# oAuth authentication - Always invalid token even if all seems ok

Tags: deezer

I know there are some similar questions but they are quite old so maybe things have changed in the latest versions.

I am trying to use the Native SDK to connect to Deezer but I am stuck at the authentication phase.

I believe I set it all right:

1. I open a browser and load the url https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=281202&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3625/deezer&perms=basic_access
2. I receive the access token into my call back on localhost:3625
3. I parse the url and extract the token
4. I give the token to dz_connect_set_access_token(app_ctxt->dzconnect,NULL, NULL,

I get the following result:

```
34986:958625 connect-session: [dz_connect_session_user_info_cb:973] api_ret:1 responsedata:0x7ff7a0118c50 34986:958679 dzuser: [dz_user_import_json_data:106] error {   "error":{
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "message":"Invalid OAuth access token.",
    "code":300   } } field e91f2fce333d4a7ab9b75cfaee3115e4_fr7d8cf7ef16ff4f3b250592154c402b
```

Indeed the message is quite clear, so I wonder why it is not recognized. what should I check? from the code, all seems ok, and the token is what I see in the redirection:

http://localhost:3625/deezer?code=fr7d8cf7ef16ff4f3b250592154c402b

Can it be because I used the same device id with the default NanoPlayer user token?

Also, I am not using the secret, is it correct?

I would appreciate very much a response and I thank you in advance.

Regards,
Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oAuth process is in two phases.

It seems you only have done the first step:

(1) https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&perms=basic_access,email

--> will return an **USER_OAUTH_CODE**

(2) https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/access_token.php?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=USER_OAUTH_CODE

--> will return the **USER_ACCESS_TOKEN**